# nodejs MySQL connection with SQLite Failover

Tags: javascript, mysql, sqlite, node.js

I'm looking for a simple example (as I'm new to node) on how to connect to MySQL to do a write (INSERT) from node.js and if that connection to the DB is unsuccessful I'd like to write the INSERT to either file so it can be replayed later or a local SQLite DB file.

Willing to take advice on if there is a better way to do this.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Regards Ric

Comment: Not sure why this post has been -1'd if there is something I've missed how about a useful comment instead of just voting down for no reason?

Comment: I think this question is okay, and will give you thumbs up again.

Comment: Thanks Alfred I was worried for a moment this was becoming one of "those" forums :( Thanks for restoring my faith

Comment: Well it would be good if you elaborate a little more on what you tried. E.g. have you looked at Node MySQL drivers (https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql) etc.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use Sequelize as it supports currently MySQL and SQLite. You could just instantiate it for both databases and write into the sqlite file if mysql access fails. If you are interested in that I could also provide an example. Check this http://sequelizejs.com/#installation and this http://sequelizejs.com/?active=dialects#dialects

Comment: This looks very interesting. I'll give it a crack and let you know how I get on thanks

Comment: if you need any help, lemme know

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like an interesting idea but I can't say I've seen anybody implement it.

That said, I can point you in the right direction. Take a look at [Felix's mysql module](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql). You should be able to catch any errors and use the [fs module](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/fs.html) to read and write to disk as a backup. Should be pretty straightforward imo!

Best of luck.

Comment: I'll give this a go and paste the answer back here.